# How import classes in android studio?

Tags: android, import, android-studio

I want to import classes in my android studio, I read some thread here at stack overflow but I cant find the editor setting under File -> Other Settings -> ? missing editor setting

Comment: What do you mean by "import classes"? It's very unclear what you are asking. Editor settings are in normal `Settings`, not `Other Settings`.

Comment: I mean just like ctrl+shift+o in eclipse. Setting options is missing under file , im using OSX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean **organizing your imports**, that's `Ctrl+Alt+O` in Android Studio (OS X).

[Have a look here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf) for all important shortcuts on OS X. Android Studio is based on IntelliJ Idea, so those are valid.

Comment: now I know, thanks again. I thought i can't do that because I haven't earned reputations yet. thanks for telling me